# how to design a brute force algorithm grouping cells? python

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, lookup-tables

i have to find a way to group the cells of the array X[ ] and Y[ ]
into pairs that hold the same character. where X[] has random ordered characters and why has exactly the same n characters.

this is the code I made

```
x = ["O", "L", "M", "S", "N", "J", "P", "T", "I", "R", "H", "G"]
y = ["S", "N", "H", "P", "T", "I", "O", "R", "L", "M", "G", "J"]

for i,char in enumerate(x):
    print(f"x[{i}] == y[{y.index(char)}]")
```

nothing major, the problem is that I have to use a brute-force approach, design an algorithm to solve the problem, and then make a more efficient algorithm, so is this a brut force approach, and do I need to make a more efficient algorithm, or is this not a brute force method and I need to make one?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is brute force.

For a more efficient approach, you need to use [a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

`list.index` has to check all elements in order, which will be slow if `Y` is large, while dictionary is a [hash table internally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and lookups in the dictionary require constant number of operations (amortized), regardless of its size.

```py
# Same approach using a dictionary
x = ["O", "L", "M", "S", "N", "J", "P", "T", "I", "R", "H", "G"]
y = ["S", "N", "H", "P", "T", "I", "O", "R", "L", "M", "G", "J"]

d = {}
for i,char in enumerate(y):
  d[char] = i

for i,char in enumerate(x):
  print(f"x[{i}] == y[{d[char]}]")
```

---

P.S. Your question looks like a homework problem. Please [read this open letter](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) about solving homework problems using Stack Overflow.

Comment: it is, i was just confused about what "brute force approach" was and thought to ask if what I did was an actual brute force or not. i guess I need to make my questions more clear and precise, I thought it was fine since I already finished the code, my bad.

also thank u for the help

Comment: Np, also check the wiki: [Brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).